# Error authenticating some packages

Tags: 15.10

I want to upgrade ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 but every time i try to upgrade i get this error please help!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a very dirty fix for this. I'm not recommending to do it this way but there are testimonials that it works. As root you need to create the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/unauth.cfg` and in this file you add the following:
`[Distro]`
`AllowUnauthenticated=yes`
 then do the upgrade and you'll see it works.
**Make sure you remove this file after the upgrade.**
You've to realize that doing it this way you're going to install packages that are not authenticated which is what the upgrade procedure tries to prevent you from. Regarding your low reputation I've to assume you're not very experienced in using Ubuntu but it would be dishonest to not tell you this. At least you can perform the upgrade now and then seek help to solve the problems if it occurs again later on.